# What is the "type" attribute in XMPP disco#info result

Tags: xmpp, service-discovery, tigase

According to [XEP-030](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0030.html#info) :

> Each <identity/> element MUST possess the 'category' and 'type' attributes specifying the category and type for the entity

I don't actually understand what does the `type` attribute stands for.

For example, when I send a disco#info query to my MUC component, I get the following answer:

```xml
<iq to='admin@localhost/986758107-tigase-8' from='muc.localhost' type='result'>
    <query xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#info'>
        <identity category='conference' name='Multi User Chat' type='text'/>
        <feature var='jabber:iq:version'/>
        <feature var='urn:xmpp:ping'/>
        <feature var='http://jabber.org/protocol/commands'/>
        <feature var='http://jabber.org/protocol/muc'/>
    </query>
</iq>
```

the `type` is set to `"text"` but what does it mean ? is there any other purpose than just creating a unique combination with `name` and `category` ? Or maybe something else ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Existing (category, type) tuples are documented here: https://xmpp.org/registrar/disco-categories.html. Conference+text is a "Text conferencing service", in other words a group chat server.